# Ruby - Ejercicio - Ayuda

Tags: ruby

Si alguien tiene tiempo les agradecería me den una mano con este ejercicio que tengo que hacer en lenguaje Ruby. El mismo tiene una excepción, y siempre caigo en ella. No logro "cazar" los pasos anteriores.

Aquí dejo el link a la plstaforma para que sea más claro:

https://mumuki.io/central/exercises/3046-metaprogramacion-introspeccion-archivo-de-configuracion

Mi respuesta es la sigueinte:

```
class Configuration
  def read_notification_mode
    if read(:notification_mode).respond_to?(:sms)
      "#{read(:sms).capitalize}NotificationMode"
    elsif read(:notification_mode).respond_to?(:facebook)
      "#{read(:facebook).capitalize}NotificationMode"
    elsif read(:notification_mode).respond_to?(:email)
      "#{read(:email).capitalize}NotificationMode"
    else
      raise "ConfigurationError"
    end
  end
end
```

Como respuesta me da un error: `ConfigurationError`, o sea, me salta directamente al `raise`.

Probé sólo con `.respond_to(:sms)` -x ejemplo, y pasa igual-.

Muchas gracias por leer. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás utilizando el método `respond_to?` en un `String`, por lo tanto cada evaluación resulta en `false`.

Lo que debes evaluar es si el valor de `read(:notification_mode)` contiene `sms`, `facebook` o `email` y, en caso que así sea, debes instanciar la clase correspondiente (i.e. `SmsNotificationMode`, `FacebookNotificationMode` o `EmailNotificationMode`.

Para comparar el valor puedes utilizar el método `include?` y para instanciar la clase debes utilizar `Kernel.const_get`; te quedaría algo así:

```
class Configuration
  def read_notification_mode
     mode = read(:notification_mode)

    if %w[sms facebook email].include?(mode)
      Kernel.const_get("#{mode.capitalize}NotificationMode").new
    else
      raise ConfigurationError
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Gerry por tomarte el tiempo y explicérmelo. Dentro de mis diversas hipótesis había puesto el const_get como posible opción pero no entendía relacionado con qué. Tampoco que entendí la relación entre el pedido de instanciar y el Kernel. ¿Esto ocurre pq en el Kernel están todas las clases por defecto, entonces lo llamo?

Comment: No, lo que hace `Kernel.get_const` es convertir un cadena (i.e. `String`) a un objeto. Por ejemplo `"SmsNotificationMode"` es el nombre de una clase, pero solo eso, es decir, una cadena de caracteres. Con `Kernel.get_const` se convierte en una _Clase_  (i.e. objeto `Class`) a partir de la cual puedes instanciar un objeto (a través del método `new`).

Comment: Mil gracias Gerry :-)

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que entendí en el mensaje que mandaste, lo que retorna `read(:notification_mode)` es un string, por lo que podrías hacer algo como:

```rb
class Configuration
  def read_notification_mode
    if read(:notification_mode) == 'sms'
      "#{'sms'capitalize}NotificationMode"
    elsif read(:notification_mode) == 'facebook'
      "#{'facebook'.capitalize}NotificationMode"
    elsif read(:notification_mode) == 'email'
      "#{'email'.capitalize}NotificationMode"
    else
      raise "ConfigurationError"
    end
  end
end
```

incluso, no meter tantos `if`:

```rb
class Configuration
 def read_notification_mode
    raise "ConfigurationError" unless ['sms', 'facebook', 'email'].include? read(:notification_mode)
    "#{read(:notification_mode).capitalize}NotificationMode"
  end
end
```

donde `raise "ConfigurationError" unless ['sms', 'facebook', 'email'].include? read(:notification_mode)`
valida la respuesta.

Espero ayude en algo :)

Comment: Hola Estebes, gracias por responder. Con este resultado aun falla. Fijate la otra respuesta. Necesitana usar el método constant_get sobre el Kernell.
Muchas gracias.